# Issue while parsing xml in AngularJs

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to parse below mentioned string to XML format.

```
var postData = '<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.0.0"'+
  'xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"'+
  'xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"'+
  'xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">'+
  '<wfs:Update typeName="Sample:ebs">'+
    '<wfs:Property>'+
      '<wfs:Name>tp</wfs:Name>'+
      '<wfs:Value>'+populationvalue+'</wfs:Value>'+
    '</wfs:Property>'+
    '<ogc:Filter>'+
      '<ogc:FeatureId fid="'+this.selectedEBS+'"/>'+
    '</ogc:Filter>'+
  '</wfs:Update>'+
'</wfs:Transaction>'
```

I am using below code to do so.

```
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(postData, "text/xml");
```

but I'm getting this error when doing so:

> error on line 1 at column 47: attributes construct error

Answer (score 0):

There's no whitespace between the attributes:

Change

```
'<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.0.0"'+
  'xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"'+
```

to

```
'<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.0.0"'+
  ' xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"'+
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

My Bad My bad

I forgot to include \n

```
var postData = '<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.0.0"\n'+
  'xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"\n'+
  'xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"\n'+
  'xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">\n'+
  '<wfs:Update typeName="Sample:ebs">\n'+
    '<wfs:Property>\n'+
      '<wfs:Name>tp</wfs:Name>\n'+
      '<wfs:Value>'+populationvalue+'</wfs:Value>\n'+
    '</wfs:Property>\n'+
    '<ogc:Filter>\n'+
      '<ogc:FeatureId fid="'+this.selectedEBS+'"/>\n'+
    '</ogc:Filter>\n'+
  '</wfs:Update>\n'+
'</wfs:Transaction>\n
```

'